# How can I use Selenium webdriver to locate page elements on Google Hangouts whose XPath values change randomly over time?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, google-hangouts

I am trying to control Google Hangouts with Selenium's Chromedriver on Python 3.4. To locate page elements on the [Google Hangouts start page](http://hangouts.google.com/start), I am using `find_elements_by_xpath()`. However, When I inspect a page element there, I notice that its XPath value changes over time. For example, the mute button has an XPath value that seemingly randomly shifts between `//*[@id=":sv.rt"]/div/div[2]` and `//*[@id=":sw.rt"]/div/div[2]`.

Am I doing something wrong? If not, can anyone suggest a workaround (e.g. locate the page element by its text description) so that I can keep being able to press the mute/unmute button using the same Python command always?

Comment: This could be because they want you to use the [Google Hangouts API](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/getting-started) rather than violating their ToS and scraping the page instead.

Comment: Does it matter to you whether they're actively breaking code that tries to scrape the page, or just not caring whether they break code that relies on things they explicitly never documented and therefore changing it whenever it's convenient?

Comment: @abarnert Sorry, total novice here. And not too sure about what you mean with your second comment. I'm just trying to control Hangouts from Python. So, if there's no workaround here, and I decide to take the Google Hangouts API path, as you suggest, will I need to sign up for Google Cloud (which AFAIK is not free after a month), install Google Cloud SDK, and learn about how to use the Google App Engine, etc. or will just being logged into my Google account in some browser be sufficient to control the Hangouts from Python?

Comment: Part of the reason Google doesn't want you to scrape their pages is that they can track how people use the API (which I'm sure is worth money to them for advertising purposes), can make you pay for access if you're using it for non-free purposes, etc. If you're trying to use Google resources in a way that's against Google's interests, and that they (in most cases) explicitly disallow, you shouldn't be too surprised if Google doesn't make it easy for you.

Comment: It's always a good idea to stay away from Google if you can. Google apps are traps specially for novice `Selenium` users

Answer (score 0):

Try to change XPath query to something like this

```
//*[substring(@id, string-length(@id) - string-length('.rt') +1) = '.rt']/div/div[2]
```

May be checking, if `id` ends with `".rt"` will be enough.

Comment: Thanks. But for some reason, this is catching `//*[@id=":sv.rt"]/div/div[2]` but not `//*[@id=":sw.rt"]/div/div[2]`. `try` and `except` seems to work, though, as there is a small number of cases, namely two that I know of so far.